# pandas: Grouping by time stamp

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>>> data_frame
                                                       flog  \
                                                      first   
0037B4F499705D725C2B3B00956B574E                        NaT   
009A27C31C21B5C47ADD76F1C0158864                        NaT   
016E73F1038CE46AF4A619453AC7DE70 2014-06-03 05:03:38.869000   
0250F3B15665E8B00F7D58CCA8C2C8F4 2014-06-03 05:04:38.869000   
0260FA375596B150DF8B4D7E3CA2D934 2014-06-03 05:04:44.015000
```

I need to group on a minute-by-minute basis.
For eg, It should be able to say `2014-06-03 05:04`: `2`, `2014-06-03 05:03`:`1`

How can I do this in pandas?

UPDATE:
DATA is actually this:

```
>>>> data_frame
                                                       flog  \                      glog \
                                                      first                         first
0037B4F499705D725C2B3B00956B574E                        NaT    2014-06-03 05:03:38.869000
009A27C31C21B5C47ADD76F1C0158864                        NaT    2014-06-03 05:04:38.869000
016E73F1038CE46AF4A619453AC7DE70 2014-06-03 05:03:38.869000    2014-06-03 05:05:38.869000
0250F3B15665E8B00F7D58CCA8C2C8F4 2014-06-03 05:04:38.869000                           NaT
0260FA375596B150DF8B4D7E3CA2D934 2014-06-03 05:04:44.015000                           naT
```

How can I display:

`TIME                 flog      glog 
                    first     first
2014-06-03 05:03:       1         1
2014-06-03 05:04:       2         1
2014-06-03 05:05:       0         1`

Comment: look up the `resample` function (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `resample`. Note that the `NaT` are currently a bug (in 0.14.0), so you need to drop them first.

```
In [18]: df.dropna().set_index('date').resample('1T',how='count')
Out[18]: 
                     value
date                      
2014-06-03 05:03:00      1
2014-06-03 05:04:00      2
```

Comment: I should've mentioned this is the question. But how would I do this if I have several `date` columns like `('flog', 'first'), ('flog', 'last')`...

Comment: ``.set_index(('flog','first'))``. will set the index from a multi-index column. resampling with multiple date columns doesn't make sense. you should show an example of what you are actually trying to do (or open a new question).

Comment: you would need to resample these columns separately then ``concat`` them as they could have different ranges, something like: ``concat([ df.set_index(col).resample(....) for col in columns_that_i_want ], axis=1)``